# Visual Studio Docker debug failed. System.ArgumentException: The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root')

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am working with a ASP dotnet 6 project and it working fine when build a docker container with external commands or debugging with IIS. But when debugging with docker support provided by visual studio it ended with below error inside the container.

Program.cs file content

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Here is the error inside the container

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: The path must be absolute. (Parameter 'root')
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.<>c.<UseStaticWebAssetsCore>b__1_0(String contentRoot)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticWebAssets.ManifestStaticWebAssetFileProvider..ctor(StaticWebAssetManifest manifest, Func`2 fileProviderFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssetsCore(IWebHostEnvironment environment, Stream manifest)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets.StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.<>c.<ConfigureWebDefaults>b__9_0(WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder cb)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<ConfigureAppConfiguration>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.BootstrapHostBuilder.RunDefaultCallbacks(ConfigurationManager configuration, HostBuilder innerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder..ctor(WebApplicationOptions options, Action`1 configureDefaults)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(String[] args)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\workspace\my\mdo\xx\src\xxx\Program.cs:line 1
Aborted
```

Comment: It's a known issue. I encountered it myself just today. Basically, the framework is trying to find a drive root (e.g. C:\) in a Unix environment. the Issue hs been reported multiple times with no fix in site. This basically means that asp.net does not work on Unix Oses.

Comment: This was a known issue (https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/320) where the tooling in VS needed to be updated to respond to a change in the output from Docker-Compose. Which version of VS and docker-compose are you using? This should have been fixed in 17.1.

Comment: @NathanCarlson-MSFT I just ran into this issue (only the .net 7 project is suffering, .net 8 is not, but I need them both). Latest preview VS: 17.9.0 Preview 1.1... can't believe this.

Comment: @Nwn have you found any workaround/solution to this?